# Android : Displaying multiple smaller images on top of big image and text inside small image

Tags: java, android, image, android-framelayout

I am working on an Android application in which I have one container called as Section and there can be Note objects inside it. The use-case is that a user can put multiple notes in a section and organize them. Currently I am to display the section names retrieved from the server with a background image.

Now my problem is how can I display the multiple notes received from the server inside the section.

I understand that this can be achieved by FrameLayout, but a dynamic Note count is what my problem is.

Please note that the count of notes can vary, depending upon user.

Here is the original screenshot of how sections look currently :

[image: Original image with each image as section]

Now when you would add notes, it ideally should look like this :

[image: Screenshot with notes]

Each of those blocks inside the section contains Note objects. To display its contents, I want to show a note block kind of image and just few words
of the note contents. 
Currently I have code to retrieve the Notes from the server, sections can be displayed, but I really have no idea how to proceed because notes can be dynamic. Here is my code so far.

```
public class GroupSectionActivity extends Activity {

    private SectionServiceImpl sectionService = new SectionServiceImpl();

    private NoteServiceImpl noteService = new NoteServiceImpl();

    private static volatile List<RestSection> restSectionList = new ArrayList<>();

    private static volatile List<RestNote> restNoteList = new ArrayList<>();

    private static volatile Long groupAccountId;

    private static volatile Integer canvasid;

    ListView listView;

    SectionLazyAdapter sectionLazyAdapter;

    static final String msectionname = "msectionname";
    static final String msectionid = "msectionid";


    Button addSectionButton;

    EditText sectionName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sectionlayout);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            groupAccountId = extras.getLong("groupid");
            canvasid = extras.getInt("canvasid");
        }

        restSectionList = this.sectionService.getSectionByCanvas(canvasid);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> restSectionArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (RestSection restSection : restSectionList) {

            HashMap<String, String> sectionDisplay = new HashMap<>();
            sectionDisplay.put("msectionid", String.valueOf(restSection.getMsectionid()));
            sectionDisplay.put("msectionname", restSection.getMsectionname());
            restSectionArrayList.add(sectionDisplay);
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.seclist);

        sectionLazyAdapter = new SectionLazyAdapter(this, restSectionArrayList);

        listView.setAdapter(sectionLazyAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                int sectionId = restSectionList.get(position).getMsectionid();
                Log.d("Sectionid is ", String.valueOf(sectionId));
                /*Intent intent = new Intent(GroupSectionActivity.this, GroupSectionActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("groupid", groupAccountId);
                intent.putExtra("sectionid", sectionId);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();*/

            }
        });
```

BaseAdapter to manage the guys :

```
public class SectionLazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;


    public SectionLazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_group_section, null);

        TextView sectionName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.sectionname); // title
     //   ImageView sectionImage=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.sectionimage); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> sectionList = new HashMap<String, String>();
        sectionList = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        sectionName.setText(sectionList.get(GroupSectionActivity.msectionname));
         return vi;
    }
}
```

activity_group_section.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sectionimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/sectionbackground"
           />
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sectionname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textView"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

sectionlayout.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="{relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/seclist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sectionAddButton">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sectionAddButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sectionbackground"
        android:text="Add Section" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sectionNameTextField"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sectionAddButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sectionAddButton"
        android:hint="Section Name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sectionAddButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope the question is clear, if there is anything missing, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the notes in a dynamic way, you should implement a GridView inside each container, if you set the right margin to each note inside the Grid, the component will dimension itself to fit your section.

The GridView adapter is really simple, works just like the ListView adapter, you will just need to define the number of columns, you can do this in the XML, or programmatically in your Java code.

```
   <GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="3"/>
```

Comment: Where will the GridView go exactly out of both the xmls?

Comment: Inside your activity_group_section.xml, you can place the GridView just below the sectionname TextView, inside the LinearLayout, and align the GridView inside the Section as you like. This way, you will create a GridView for each section you insert in your ListView.

Comment: Hi man, I have the gridview, can you help me with elements in it because the gridview is looking a bit weird. I have created a chatroom, whenever you have time. Link : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86759/for-thomas-only

Comment: The problem I am having is you have told me to set GridView in activity_group_section.xml, but this XML is loaded by extending baseAdapter and I have no way of inserting elements inside it from the class where I am extending activity.

Answer (score 1):

First let me point out that Thomaz is right and you should use a GridView.
It's the right way to go both for your needs and ease of use, but more importantly for it's ability to recycle it's views.
**If you won't use any form of view recycling you might get out of memory exception.**

But now you face another problem: you want it to be shown in sections.
Why is that a problem? Because:
A) Both the ListView and the GridView do recycling with their child views, and now that each child view of the ListView is a single GridView, which holds inside of it more Views, it's a pretty complex thing to manage. No impossible, but pretty complex.
B) Because of the fact that both the ListView and the GridView are scrollable (and because of that fact are recyclable) there is an issue of scrolling inside scrolling that needs to be resolved.

Luckily I cam across an answer: [SuperSLiM](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM) (Formally [StickyGridHeaders](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders)).
This should provide you with an easy solution which suites your needs.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please give me a headstart on how I can use the code for the task, as the countries example contains only text and country names.

Comment: Well you can check the [CountryNamesAdapter](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM/blob/7c8d9f2bbcbad2ce47058036f974624aff102d9f/example/src/main/java/com/tonicartos/superslimexample/CountryNamesAdapter.java) but instead of using the string array and the first letter of a country use your data.
For instance if your data is a list of sections, and every section contains a list of Notes, you can create a for loop in a for loop to create the list of items.

Comment: Thanks, I will use it.